# Excel: Sum total of cells displaying "COMPLETE" based on ID in column B, ignoring duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Edit: Reworded, provided table & examples and a better explanation.

I am a novice at excel; I've made a few formulas, but this one has really stumped me. I'm unable to search for each value individually because they change day to day and it would require too much upkeep to re-write the formula every day with each unique ID - when one is completed, it will not be on the list the next day.

To explain: Each ID in column B can appear multiple times, and can have different statuses associated with it - (COMPLETE, IN PROGRESS, etc.) I need cell C2 to display the total amount of IDs marked "COMPLETE", ignoring duplicate values, and only being counted if every instance of the ID is marked "COMPLETE". So if the ID 48324 appears 5 times, I only want the counter in C2 to register it if all 5 are marked "COMPLETE", and then treat the entire 5 "COMPLETE"s as 1 value for the count. So all 5 "COMPLETE"s would only increase the total "COMPLETE" count by 1.

I've tried vlookup and countif, but I'm fairly out of my depth and I need advice for how best to proceed. Thanks!

| STATUS | ID | TOTAL COMPLETE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COMPLETE | 14462 |  |
| COMPLETE | 48324 |  |
| NOT IN PROGRESS | 46784 |  |
| COMPLETE | 34734 |  |
| COMPLETE | 48324 |  |
| COMPLETE | 48324 |  |
| COMPLETE | 35567 |  |
| IN PROGRESS | 14462 |  |
| COMPLETE | 35567 |  |
| NOT IN PROGRESS | 14462 |  |
| COMPLETE | 56569 |  |
| IN PROGRESS | 24563 |  |
| IN PROGRESS | 34567 |  |
| IN PROGRESS | 48324 |  |
| COMPLETE | 56569 |  |
| NOT IN PROGRESS | 23533 |  |
| NOT IN PROGRESS | 48324 |  |
| COMPLETE | 86576 |  |
| COMPLETE | 36735 |  |
| IN PROGRESS | 48324 |  |

Comment: could you do two things.  First put that table in as text so we can copy paste.  Second, with the data provided, what is the expected result.  You are more likely to get an answer if you do those two items.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I added the table as text, reworded the explanation, and added an example scenario.

Comment: What would be the expected outcome of the data provided?  What is the total number we should get?

Comment: The outcome should be the total times "COMPLETE" appears in column A. Since each ID can be marked "COMPLETE" multiple times, I need to find a way to only count each ID's "COMPLETE" status once, and only if every instance of an ID is marked "COMPLETE". Unfortunately, since the IDs change daily, I can't just search for each one specifically. In cell C2 should be the counter, displaying the total "COMPLETE"s from column A.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  Given the data you gave what is the final outcome: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... ?  Manually figure it out to ensure we are getting what we should get.

Comment: The outcome should be 5, it looks like. Your formula looks to have been exactly correct for what I needed as well, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS to get the data and SUMPRODUCT to sum the results.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A:A,"COMPLETE",B:B,B2:B21)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B21))/COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B21))
```

`(COUNTIFS(A:A,"COMPLETE",B:B,B2:B21)=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B21))` returns 1 or 0 depending on if the counts match, meaning all are marked "complete" for each ID or Not.

Then we divide that by the number of times the ID is in the list so the whole adds to 1.

Then we sum.

[image]